# How can you restrict a GCP role to only write to temporary BigQuery tables

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, temp-tables, google-cloud-iam

At a minimum, to write query results to a table, you must be granted the following permissions:

- bigquery.tables.create permissions to create a new table
- bigquery.tables.updateData to write data to a new table, overwrite a table, or append data to a table
- bigquery.jobs.create to run a query job

(According to [GCP BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#required_permissions))

There's no distinction between temporary and permanent tables (which I find problematic from an IAM perspective). To make it worse, it looks like those permissions have to be granted on the datasets and tables which are accessed by the query that creates the temp table (or at least that's what I assume based on my current experience with Great Expectations). Say you want to create a temp table based on a production table using an SA, you'd have to give that SA `updateData` permissions.

So I wonder whether there's a way to limit those permissions to temporary tables only, e.g. by specifying a table name pattern which is specific to temp tables. The problem I'm facing is that temp tables are an internal concept and `they are not visible using any of the standard list or other table manipulation methods`, (see docs above). So how do you restrict the permission to temp tables if you don't even know their name, let alone naming pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a table is a table in BigQuery, temporary or not. In similar use-case, I use a separated dataset "unsafe", a kind of landing zone, and then I have other processes that read those data and merge them with production.

If those tables are not visible or exposed, it's also fine, don't grant the permission to view the table to other users.

---

Ultimately, you can also create the temporary table in a separated project if you want a separation at project level (depends on how you manage your IAM policies, at the resource or at the project level)

Comment: Yeah, creating the temp tables in separate projects/datasets is definitely the way to go from an IAM perspective and how I would like to set it up. Unfortunately, Great Expectations deprecated that behaviour a few versions ago (who knows why, probably because that's how they do it with all other databases). So now I'm stuck with temp tables in the same datasets as the source tables.

Comment: The problem I have is that I need a service account to create temp tables and I need to grant the role create and update privileges. So I would like to restrict that SA as much as possible, e.g. by limiting those permissions to temp tables. I don't know what name pattern those tables have though because they're hidden/internal.

Comment: I don't know Great Expectation so much, but, when you create a table in BigQuery, the table fully qualified name is "project.dataset.table". So, if you use that, will you be able to overpass the limitation?

Comment: I have now figured out that the pattern of Great Expectation tables is `gx_temp_{RANDOM_ID}`. Unfortunately, it looks like that doesn't help at all, because GCP/BigQuery doesn't support granting permissions on table (or dataset/project) names using wildcards. I assumed it would, because it's possible in e.g. AWS Athena using the standard IAM policy syntax. Can you confirm that this is not possible in BQ (except maybe through Data Classification which I don't want to get into unless I have to).

Comment: Yes, I confirm. IAM Condition does not support BigQUery resources. And even if it was the case, I would discourage you to use it (hard to maintain and to debug). Mitigating the limitation of Great Expectation is your best option I think.